blink not working in brave browser
import { ActionGetResponse, ACTIONS_CORS_HEADERS } from "@solana/actions";
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

export const OPTIONS = GET

export function GET(request: NextRequest) {

  const actionMetaData: ActionGetResponse = {
    icon: "https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/tin-can-frying-pan-17273506.jpg",
    title: "Choose your agent",
    description: "Who will win",
    label: "Select",
    // links: {
    //   actions: []
    // },
  }

  return NextResponse.json(actionMetaData, { headers: ACTIONS_CORS_HEADERS });
}

Above code snippet works fine in firefox but not in brave. I am using dial.to for testing
error:  GET http://localhost:3000/api/vote net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
575-d832fb2fecfcad8d.js:14 [@dialectlabs/blinks-core] Failed to fetch action TypeError: Failed to fetch

Turning off shields for dial.to/ resolved the issue
